# Pandas Time Series shows NaN after converting entries to float

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter

I'm trying to get a time series going from a dataframe. My dataframe contains two desired columns - Timestamp and Speed. This is my code so far:

Step 1: I replaced all the spaces in the desired Speed column with 0

```
bus1354['Speed'].replace('   ',0,inplace=True)
```

Step 2: I then check to see if there are any NaN values in the Speed column after this

```
assert not bus1354['Speed'].isnull().any()
```

Step 3: I then check the first few entries of Timestamp and Speed columns together in the dataframe

```
bus1354[['Timestamp','Speed']].head()
```

This is the result I get (so far so good):

[image]

Step 4: I then truncate the Timestamp so as to only show hh:mm:ss and remove the milliseconds. I also convert to datetime format.

```
bus1354['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(bus1354['Timestamp'].apply(lambda x : x[:7]))
```

Step 5: I check the result of the truncation

```
bus1354['Timestamp'].head()
```

Here's what that looks like:

[image]

Step 6: I then convert the speed to float64 from non-null object

```
bus1354['Speed'] = bus1354['Speed'].apply(float)
```

Step 7: I create a timerange and Time Series

```
bstimeRng = bus1354['Timestamp']
bs1354Ser = pd.Series(bus1354['Speed'], index=bstimeRng)
```

Step 8: Once I output my Time Series however, I get a bunch of NaN's for my Speed column.

```
bs1354Ser
```

[image]

I'm still learning the ins and outs of pandas so bear with me if this sounds like a basic question. Why is it that even after I changed the Speed column into float64, the Time Series still shows my desired Speed values as "NaN"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here better is use [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html):

```
s1354Ser = bus1354.set_index('Timestamp')['Speed']
```

**Sample**:

```
bus1354 = pd.DataFrame(
        {'Timestamp':['08:38:00:009','08:38:00:013','08:38:00:019'],
        'Speed':[42,42,43]})


print (bus1354)
      Timestamp  Speed
0  08:38:00:009     42
1  08:38:00:013     42
2  08:38:00:019     43

bus1354['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(bus1354['Timestamp'].str[:7])
bus1354['Speed'] = bus1354['Speed'].astype(float)

s1354Ser = bus1354.set_index('Timestamp')['Speed']
print (s1354Ser)
Timestamp
2019-01-19 08:38:00    42.0
2019-01-19 08:38:00    42.0
2019-01-19 08:38:00    43.0
Name: Speed, dtype: float64
```

---

Missing values in your solution is problem data alignment:

```
#sample data
df = pd.DataFrame(
        {'a':[0,2,3],
         'b':[41,42,43]})


print (df)
   a   b
0  0  41
1  2  42
2  3  43
```

If check index of original data:

```
print (df.index.tolist())
[0, 1, 2]
```

And values of column `a` used for new index:

```
print (df['a'].tolist())
[0, 2, 3]
```

Then `Series` contructor if possible align data - old index from original by new index from `a` column, if value not exist are created `NaN`s:

```
s = pd.Series(df['b'], index=df['a'])
print (s)
a
0    41.0 <-align by 0 from original index
2    43.0 <-align by 2 from original index
3     NaN <- not exist 3, so NaN
Name: b, dtype: float64
```

But if convert values of `Speed` to numpy 1d array by [`values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.values.html), then array have no index like `Series`:

```
s1354Ser = pd.Series(bus1354['Speed'].values, index=bstimeRng)

s = pd.Series(df['b'].values, index=df['a'])
print (s)
a
0    41
2    42
3    43
dtype: int64
```